# iOS SDK - Detect movement of user

Tags: xcode4.2, accelerometer, gyroscope, ios5

in iOS SDK, how to detect movement of user? Here is the assumption:

- The user holds the iPhone horizontal ( parallel to the floor )
- The iPhone is 3GS / 4 / 4s
- Location service is ON (do I need this?)
- The user is walking around, so I have to detect how long he walk (doesn't need to be accurate)
- The OS supported are iOS 4 & 5

I already implemented `CMDeviceMotion` for direction, tilt & pitch detection, but I still can't figure out how to detect the movement of user. Please advice. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to detect the movement of the device precisely using accelerometer and gyroscope only.

Because the accelerometer provides accelerations i.e. the 2nd derivation of time you need to integrate twice. Although the sensors are pretty exact this leads to huge errors after a few cycles due to error propagation. As long as there is no fixed reference point to recalibrate the calculations even heavy maths like Kalman filters does not provide an acceptable result.

If the user is running instead of walking, you get a slightly different situation because of the stronger up and down movements that can be used as a pedometer. I don't know if anybody has managed to get this working but it seems basically possible to me especially in combination with GPS. Even then there are some remaining problems like standby mode or interrupts by phone calls pushing your app in the background.